BeautifulSoup webscraping find_all( ):
I am trying to get the time and price of the ones with the green circle, to save them and send the data to https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js.
https://imgur.com/NSmNxL7
Google collab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HvO7AWvBhP1_epfiAKSE1aE1zBUHvJ9O#scrollTo=evP9Tallp-d5
When I use this line of code,
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "col-xs-11 col-lg-5 template-tlh__colors")


for div in divs:
  print(div)
  print(" ")


It shows me this data,
<div class="col-xs-11 col-lg-5 template-tlh__colors">
<div class="template-tlh__colors--hours">
<div class="template-tlh__colors--hours-info">
<div class="template-tlh__colors--hours-circle template-tlh__background-color-high"> </div>
<span itemprop="description">20:00 - 21:00</span>
</div>
<div class="template-tlh__colors--hours-price template-tlh__color-high">
<span itemprop="price">0.06643
€/kWh</span>
<meta content="EUR" itemprop="priceCurrency"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="col-xs-11 col-lg-5 template-tlh__colors">
<div class="template-tlh__colors--hours">
<div class="template-tlh__colors--hours-info">
<div class="template-tlh__colors--hours-circle template-tlh__background-color-high"> </div>
<span itemprop="description">21:00 - 22:00</span>
</div>
<div class="template-tlh__colors--hours-price template-tlh__color-high">
<span itemprop="price">0.07924
€/kWh</span>
<meta content="EUR" itemprop="priceCurrency"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>

But, I don't know how to extract the time and price data (I marked them in bold). To be able to send them later with the whatsapp bot.
The website is https://tarifaluzhora.es/

I don't know how to extract the time and price data Look for <span itemprop="description"> and <span itemprop="price"> elements, and get their text.  What is the difficulty?

Here is an example how you can get time/price/color from that page to pandas dataframe:
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://tarifaluzhora.es/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for row in soup.select(".row:not(:has(.row)):has([itemprop=price])"):
    time = row.select_one('[itemprop="description"]')
    price = row.select_one('[itemprop="price"]')

    color = time.find_previous("div")["class"][-1]

    if "high" in color:
        color = "high"
    elif "low" in color:
        color = "low"
    else:
        color = "default"

    all_data.append(
        {
            "Time": time.text,
            "Price": price.text.replace("\n", " "),
            "Color": color,
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)

Prints:
             Time          Price    Color
0   00:00 - 01:00  0.07835 €/kWh     high
1   01:00 - 02:00  0.07402 €/kWh     high
2   02:00 - 03:00  0.07551 €/kWh     high
3   03:00 - 04:00  0.07142 €/kWh     high
4   04:00 - 05:00   0.0686 €/kWh     high
5   05:00 - 06:00  0.06724 €/kWh     high
6   06:00 - 07:00  0.06988 €/kWh     high
7   07:00 - 08:00  0.06922 €/kWh     high
8   08:00 - 09:00  0.06694 €/kWh     high
9   09:00 - 10:00  0.04585 €/kWh      low
10  10:00 - 11:00  0.04314 €/kWh      low
11  11:00 - 12:00  0.04135 €/kWh      low
12  12:00 - 13:00  0.04095 €/kWh      low
13  13:00 - 14:00  0.04074 €/kWh      low
14  14:00 - 15:00  0.04164 €/kWh      low
15  15:00 - 16:00  0.04227 €/kWh      low
16  16:00 - 17:00  0.04262 €/kWh      low
17  17:00 - 18:00  0.04444 €/kWh      low
18  18:00 - 19:00  0.04552 €/kWh      low
19  19:00 - 20:00  0.05339 €/kWh      low
20  20:00 - 21:00  0.06643 €/kWh     high
21  21:00 - 22:00  0.07924 €/kWh     high
22  22:00 - 23:00  0.06724 €/kWh     high
23  23:00 - 24:00  0.05605 €/kWh  default


How can I do, so that everything I get from the printout is saved in a .csv file?
Google collab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HvO7AWvBhP1_epfiAKSE1aE1zBUHvJ9O#scrollTo=Iy7Lk1NtZTEN
I added this, but it only saves "Time" "Price" "Color".                                                                                                                                       file = open("webscraper.csv", "w") writer = csv.writer(file) writer.writerow(df) file.close()

@diaverso To save datavframe as CSV you do df.to_csv('your_file.csv', index=False)
